# How to fetch "return Response::json(array([....,....])) " data in Vuejs

Tags: eloquent, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.7

How to fetch Laravel multiple return "array" data in Vuejs

Below Laravel code is working properly.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $model = Fabricsbooking::with(['fileno','fileno.merchandiser', 'fileno.buyer', 'items.yarncount'])
        ->findOrFail($id);

        $yarn = Fabricsbookingitem::with('yarncount')->where('fabricsbooking_id', $id)
            ->groupBy('yarncount_id')
            ->selectRaw('sum(qty)as yarn_qty, sum(total_yarn)as total_yarn, yarncount_id' )
            ->get();

        return Response::json(array(['model'=>$model],['yarn'=> $yarn]));


    }
```

api.js code

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function get(url, params) {
    return axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        params: params,

    })
}

export function byMethod(method, url, data) {
    return axios({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data

    })
}
```

Vue template page script:

```
<script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import {get, byMethod} from '../../lib/api'
    export default {
        data:()=>{
            return{
                show:false,
                model:{
                    items:[],
                    fileno:{},
                },
                yarn:{}

            }
        },
        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
            get(`/fabbooking/${to.params.id}`)
                .then((res)=>{
                    next(vm=> vm.setData(res))
                })
        },
        beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next){
            this.show = false
            get(`/fabbooking${to.params.id}`)
                .then((res)=>{
                    this.setData(res)
                    next()
                })
        },
        methods:{
            setData(res){
            Vue.set(this.$data, 'model', res.data.model)
                this.show=true
            },
        deleteItem(){
            byMethod('delete', `/fabbooking/${this.model.id}`)
                .then((res)=> {
                    if (res.data.deleted){
                        this.$router.push('/fabook')
                    }
                })
        }
        },
    }
</script>
```

When load the page in browser, shown below error code in Console
**"app.js:682[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined""**
Need to solutions for Vue template page script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Since the only place you use `id` is in `to.params.id` it means that `params` is undefined.

You can double check it with the following test:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
            console.log(to.params)//like this you check params has values.
        },
```

Maybe your route is not correctly configured. Did you forget the "props:true" flag for example?

More info in the docs: [vue route params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.